# revision history seems to lump together separate edits

Tags: support, editing

I posted an answer and then made several edits to it:

https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/23268/revisions

What's shown in the revision history with the summary "clarification" was actually two separate edits I made -- I added the bulk of the text in an edit that I summarized as something like "added $a$ and $b$ and how to determine them", and then made only a minor modification to that and summarized it as "clarification". That first summary and its diff don't show up in the revision history, and the diff that's shown for the summary "clarification" is actually the diff for both edits combined.

I think this is the first time that I used dollar signs in the edit summary, so the problem might be related to that.

Comment: I suspect that your "clarification" edit was done within five minutes of the first edit. The system lets you change things during five minutes without updating the time stamp of the edit (this holds for comments, answers editing of answers and editing of questions). Furthermore I assume that changing the "added $a$ and $b$" to "Clarification" has modified the summary of that edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're probably seeing that any edits within a 5-minute span of posting or edits within a 5-minute span of a new edit are grouped together, which is the intended behavior (not a bug).

See also: [Is there a grace period for correction of edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20441/is-there-a-grace-period-for-correction-of-edits)

Comment: As regards the edit summaries, this does seem like a bug -- the edit summaries don't make any sense this way; the large text insertion is not a "clarification". I assume the intent is to allow small corrections after an edit has been made without counting them as separate edits. If so, the summary of the first edit is more likely to make sense for the union of all the edits than the summary of the last edit. Either the first summary should be shown, or perhaps the summaries of all edits being bunched together.

Comment: @joriki: as this is about the behaviour of the SE software, rather than specifically a question about Math.SE, it may be better if you re-ask this question at Meta.stackoverflow, taking into account Isaac's answer above.